# Undefined value when calling function in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore, and wrote the following code:

```
export function getAllServices(uid) {
  let services = [];
  firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('services').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      services.push(doc.data());
      console.log(services);
      return services;
    })
  })
}
```

The function works b/c console.log returns the array I want. However, when I call it like this

```
const uid = 'SgUaycgJqzLbdcrOhjQtgcDzddL2';
  const services = getAllServices(uid);
  console.log(services);
```

the console log always returns as undefined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to know the cause of the problem, given that you tagged your question with `asynchronous`. Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, and your `return services;` doesn't in any way return a value from `getAllServices`. The only way to return something `getAllServices` is in the first level of code in there, but at that point your `then()` callback won't have been called yet.

The solution is to bubble up the value from inside the `then()` callback, and return it as a promise.

```
export function getAllServices(uid) {
  return firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('services').get().then(snapshot => {
    let services = [];
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      services.push(doc.data());
    })
    return services;
  })
}
```

Then you can call `getAllServices` and use the result like this:

```
const uid = 'SgUaycgJqzLbdcrOhjQtgcDzddL2';
getAllServices(uid).then(function(services) {
  console.log(services);
});
```

---

You can make the above a bit more familiar looking by using modern JavaScript's `async` and `await` keywords

```
export async function getAllServices(uid) {
  let services = [];
  return firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('services').get().then(snapshot => {
    let services = [];
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      services.push(doc.data());
    })
    return services;
  })
}

const uid = 'SgUaycgJqzLbdcrOhjQtgcDzddL2';
let services = await getAllServices(uid);
console.log(services);
```

Just keep in mind that this is all (wonderfully readable) syntactic sugar, and that the data is still being retrieved asynchronously behind the scenes.

Comment: When I add the then, it still returns undefined. And when I use async function, it says I can't use keyword await outside an async function.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed there was another mistake in your `getAllServices`. I fixed that in my answer.